# Please merge [vim-navigation] into [vim]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, useless-tags

I'm pretty sure that “Vim Navigation” isn't a phrase. It's just navigation in Vim. So the tag [vim-navigation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-navigation) isn't refering to a particular software package or anything, it's just redundant with [vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim). This tag shouldn't exist, but all questions with it should have the tag [vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim).

Please merge [vim-navigation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-navigation) into [vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim) and then remove the synonym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). [vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim) was already on 7 all of them.